# R - Check that view exists in PostgreSQL

Tags: r, postgresql

Is there a simple function testing existence of a view in PostgreSQL? For tables I'm using something like:

```
table_name <- 'tmp.test'
con <- c('a','b','c','d','5432')

drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con <- dbConnect(drv, user=con[1], password=con[2], dbname=con[3], host=con[4], 
                      port=con[5])

table_exists <- dbExistsTable(con,table_name)
dbDisconnect(con)
```

But because my code accepts also views, I would need to use some query like:

```
table_name <- 'tmp.test'
con <- c('a','b','c','d','5432')

drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con <- dbConnect(drv, user=con[1], password=con[2], dbname=con[3], host=con[4], 
                 port=con[5])

sql <- paste0("select count(*) > 0 from information_schema.tables 
              where table_schema || '.' || table_name = '", table_name,"'")
table_exists <- dbGetQuery(con,sql)[1,1]

dbDisconnect(con)
```

This works, but feels like I missed some existing R function.

Update: For those interested, this is how method `dbExistsTable` is defined for PostgreSQL:

```
setMethod("dbExistsTable",
    signature(conn="PostgreSQLConnection", name="character"),
    def = function(conn, name, ...){
        qlength <- length(name)
        if(qlength == 1){
        currentschema <- dbGetQuery(conn, "SELECT current_schema()")
        res <- dbGetQuery(conn,
            paste("select tablename from pg_tables where ",
            "schemaname !='information_schema' and schemaname !='pg_catalog' ",
            "and schemaname='", postgresqlEscapeStrings(conn, currentschema[[1]]), "' ",
            "and tablename='", postgresqlEscapeStrings(conn, name), "'", sep=""))
        }
        else{
            if(qlength == 2){
            res <- dbGetQuery(conn,
                paste("select tablename from pg_tables where ",
                "schemaname !='information_schema' and schemaname !='pg_catalog' ",
                "and schemaname='", postgresqlEscapeStrings(conn, name[1]), "' ",
                "and tablename='", postgresqlEscapeStrings(conn, name[2]), "'", sep=""))
            }
        }
        return(as.logical(dim(res)[1]))
    },
    valueClass = "logical"
    )
```

This is how it works:

1. Name can be specified as character vector with one or two elements
2. If name has only one element than table is searched in `current_schema` (first schema in `search_path`)
3. If name has two elements than first is assumed to be schema and second actual name of table

Notes:

- only tables are being searched, not views (because `pg_tables` is used)
- `information_schema` and `pg_catalog` is excluded from search

Comment: The `dbTableExists` function doesn't accept a view as well? Weird. Usually, things like that will actually accept *any relation* - view, table, sequence, foreign table, etc.

Comment: @CraigRinger It does not. I added method source code to my question - it checks in `pg_tables` only. Maybe I should propose new method, something like `dbExistsRelation` or maybe it works for views for other RDBMs and it's wrong for PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

I am using RODBC package for connections with a PostgreSQL data base.

There is a function sqlTables () that will return you an information about existing tables.

Hope it will help you!